# The space of all linear maps from $U\to V$ is isomorphic to $\text{Mat}_{l\times k}(K).$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

While trying to solve the following problem

> Let $K$ be a finite field of $q$ elements. Let $U$, $V$ be vector spaces over $K$ with
>   $\dim(U) = k$, $\dim(V) = l$. How many linear maps $U \rightarrow V$ are there?

I came across the following claim [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662744/number-of-linear-maps-between-vector-spaces-over-finite-fields):

> The space of all linear maps from $U\to V$ is isomorphic to $\text{Mat}_{l\times k}(K).$

Could someone link me to a proof of this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's solved here:
[Proving isomorphism between linear maps and matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201784/proving-isomorphism-between-linear-maps-and-matrices)

And the proof is based on Matrix representation of linear transformations